# Cannot create .edmx for MySql Database with mysql.data.entity.EF6 in Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Recently i am trying to developing n-tier asp.net mvc application using Entity Framework with MySQL as the backend database. I wanted to use latest EntityFramework ie 6.9.9.0 version, so i downloaded sqlconnector package through "**Nuget package Installer**". These are the libraries that it installed for me:

## mysql.data.dll(ver. 6.9.9.0)

## mysql.data.entity.EF6(ver 6.9.9.0)

But i could not successfully create .edmx file for my project. During the final steps of creation of .edmx , it ends in the error. Here are the steps I applied:

1) first I selected '.net framework database provider' for mysql as in screenshot
[image]

2)Then I clicked '**next**' button as in the screenshot
[image]

3)Finally i **selected the tables** for the database that i want to import in the **entity data model** before i click 'finish'
[image]

4) Click on "finish" button pops up "null object reference" error.
[image]

closing the error dialog displays the "add entity model" dialog again
[image]

The process creates a blank .edmx file with not a single DB tables on it.Also I find no errors in visual studio error list at the bottom of the window.

Could anyone share insight on what could be the possible issues here, i am really stuck at the first step of code my application and has already spent almost whole day searching for solution over the internet. I personally tried many alternatives seeking for solution too, but no luck so far. Anyone's help would be truly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Which Visual Studio version?

Comment: Hi, in visual studio 2013, I am facing the problem

Comment: Install the latest EF Tools https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762

Comment: Hi @ErikEJ,                                                                                                  Thanks for the advice .I installed EF tools for the VS 2013, i still get the same errors http://screencast.com/t/W5zG8hwhJ. Am i missing something here?

Comment: That does not look like the same error to me... Maye log a bug report on the MySql support site?

Comment: Hi @ErikEJ , I agree that it may not be the same error like you have said, but this time around i found the solution which i will write down as answer and hope that will be a good hint for anyone going through the same situation as mine. Thank you for your continued replies:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow sensed that I am not using the right version of

**EF tools for Visual Studio 2013**

with corresponding version of **MYSQL server installation** and **mysqlconnector for .net**. So i downloaded and compared several versions of EF tools, MYSQL installer and MYSQL(Nuget package) for entity framework and finally found the right combination as follows:

1. Entity Framework 6.1.3 tools for Visual Studio 2013
2. MYSQL-installer-community-5.6.32.0.msi (you can find archived mysql
   version in google)
3. MYSQL(Nuget package) for entity framework like in the screen shot below:

[image]

As it worked for me , i think mysql.data dll version and mysqlconnector for net that comes with MYSQL installer should match , i have them highlighted here in picture:

[image]

After the proper installation ,i finally got EDMX diagram loaded fully and correctly upon creating one.

P.S: after every un-installation of MYSQL server version that did not work for me, I used the useful tool (Advanced_Uninstaller11.exe) to clean all left out registry entries and here is the download link for the tool 
[enter link description here](http://www.advanceduninstaller.com/MySQL-for-Visual-Studio-1_1_3-6356838ad4797617b2a4c62e5a36c89c-application.htm)

I Hope that I have explained it clearly of the problem and its resolution. I could not make any of the above points or scenario clear, hope you would comment on it and i would try to explain more and better.

And Thank you @ErikEJ for your continued support on the problem.